# Transformation quad texture to triangle form

Tags: interpolation, linear-algebra

I have texture like that (16x16 pixels)

[image]

and I want to transform it to triangle shape like that

[image]

But fully based on texture's values to compress to triangle.
As example after compressing texture pixel (1, 1) (based on top-left coordinates) will be based on every pixel righter and downer.
I have already found out that this task is simillar to matrix conversions but I can't find out how to do it.

Left triangle is a result and right quad in input.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small but complete example of an input and it's expected output?

Comment: After the edit: both input and output images appear identical to me. What's the difference?

Comment: @YakovDan It's just two nearby tiles placed
Triangle is calculated by bilinear interpolation and quad is original one